# Calculate $\int \left(1+\ln \left(1+\ln (...+\left(1+ \ln(x))\right)\right)\right) dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

This is not particularly a useful integral or one asked in an exam or anything. I just really enjoy doing random integrals and derivatives. With that being said, how can I find:

$$\int \left(1+\ln \left(1+\ln (...+\left(1+ \ln(x))\right)\right)\right) dx$$

I tried to star with the simple case of: $$\int \left(1+\ln(x)\right)dx=x\ln \left(x\right)+C$$ I then introduced the first nest. Here I did Integration by Parts with $u=1+\ln \left(1+\ln \left(x\right)\right), v'=1$:
$$\int \left(1+\ln \left(1+\ln \left(x\right)\right)\right)dx=x\left(1+\ln \left(1+\ln \left(x\right)\right)\right)-\frac{1}{e}\text{Ei}\left(\ln \left(x\right)+1\right)+C$$

However, these take quite some time and it's only the first nest. Therefore, I'm curious as to if $(a)$ such an integral does have solution and $(b)$ how to derive that situation.

PS - Again this is just a fun question and not from an exam, website or anywhere important.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a nesting applied $n$ times or infinitely many?

Comment: Originally, it was supposed to be n many times, but if after n=2, there is no anti derivative, I’m curious as to what happens when it is nested infinitely many times.

Comment: @SkiMask: Infinite case could in fact be easier (as the current answer seems to show) but I would be concerned about whether the function would be well-defined at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int 1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(1+...\ln(x)))) dx=F(x)$$

$$1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(1+...\ln(x))))=F'(x)$$

$$1+\ln(F'(x))=F'(x)$$

$$F'(x)=1$$

$$F(x)=x+c$$

Comment: That’s quite an elegant method!

Comment: Another way to see the infinite case is realizing that the integrand would be independent of $x$. Then it is trivial to see that $\int c dx = cx + C$ where $c = 1+\ln(1+\ln(1+...)) = 1$

Comment: @VarunVejalla mmm not exactly. In general $\int f(f(f(f(...f(x))))dx$ follows the same pattern, so as long as $f(x)=x$ has one real solution, we can apply the same argumentation and reach a linear solution. in the above case $f(x)=1+\ln(x)$ but if $f(x)=\tan(x)$ things would go off the charts rather quickly. Take $f(x)=1+\sqrt{x}$ and you get that corresponding integral is equal $(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})x+C$. Your reasoning does not resolve constant $c$ and is generally not even a good heuristic.

Comment: @AleksandarPerisic I said in the infinite case in my comment. Definitely not in the finite case, since that would depend on $x$.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I was talking about infinite case as well. Take $1+exp(1+exp(1+exp(1+...exp(x))))$, or $1+\sin(1+\sin(1+\sin(1+...\sin(x))))$... You cannot decide on $x$ disappearing from the expression because the expression is infinite. You cannot do that even in case of $\ln(x)$, you would need quite some argumentation over what the used function is actually doing to the expression.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you. Well the reason it doesn't depend on $x$ is that $1+\ln(x) \le x$, so essentially it would keep going down until the fixed point of $x = 1$ for $x \ge 1$. For $x < 1$, $1 + \ln(x)$ would eventually not be defined, so the value does not exist there.

Comment: Infinite $1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(1+\ln(...$ is defined everywhere, which is a little bit complicated to prove in the complex domain, but the final integral is real function and has no limitation.